# Get everything as seperate column after and before special character in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the values in one the column

```
"A","1","Created","DO",....
"B","2","Update","Cancel",....
```

And want the results like each in seperate column
`A` as `col1`, `1` as `col2`, `Created` as `col3`
And `B` as `col1`, `2` as `col2`, `Update` as `col3` like this

```
select substr(data, instr(substr(data, 6),'","')+8,1)
```

Can someone help me

Comment: Are those double quotes part of the data?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Yes double quote is part of the data and using SQL DB

Comment: what sql db do you use?
Oracle, MS sql, mysql, postgresql or any other? The syntax will differ depends on what is your db

Comment: @user3686599: "SQL" is the name of a the query language. Every relational database is a "SQL DB"

Answer (score 0):

If youre database is mysql you can use this:

```
    SELECT 
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourColumn,',',1)),',',-1),'"','') AS col1,
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourColumn,',',2)),',',-1),'"','') AS col2,
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourColumn,',',3)),',',-1),'"','') AS col3
    FROM youreTable
```

Comment: No i dont have mysql. SUBSTRING_INDEX is not working

Comment: Can someone help me with this